# how to set owin token authentication header in angular resource

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I am very new to what i am currently working now. I may not be explain well but as much i have understood i would like to put my understanding on the same.

I am using the Owin token based authentication for web api, for login i am calling the token method which returns the access token. I would like to know how to secure our web api, so that without the access token it should not allow to call the web api method. I am using the angular js resource, i believe we need to define the header in angularjs service part, but where and how exactly i do not have any idea, can anyone please help me on this.

Example:-

This my service written in angularjs,

```
sghServices.factory('GlobalSettingsService', function ($resource) {
return $resource("../Api/eClaim/SecondGlobalSettings",
    {},
    {
        post: {
            method: 'POST', isArray: false,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        },
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

This is web api method

```
[Authorize]        
[Route("~/Api/eClaim/GlobalSettings")]
[HttpGet]
public ReportAndeCliam GetGlobalSettings()
{
    //Code Wriiten here
}
```

As of now i am able to access the web api without access token, i wanna design in such a way if token is not available it should not allow to use the [Authorized] web api method.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You can make filter in MVC API code for checking security key from header.

Comment: As i have seen in an example, once we use the [Authorize] attribute on the method, it makes the web api method secure and it won't let us allow to call the web api method without access token. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right.. I update my answer. just check it out.

Comment: Do you generate token by yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make filter class in api like below.

```
public class AuthorizeAPIAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calls when a process requests authorization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext">The action context, which encapsulates information for using <see cref="T:S:System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute" />.</param>
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!ConfigItems.APISecurityEnable)
        {
            return;
        }

        var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
        var security = headers.Any(x => x.Key == "Security");
        if (security)
        {
            var value = headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "Security").Value.FirstOrDefault();
            if (value != null)
            {
                string token = value;
                if (token == ConfigItems.APIToken)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        actionContext.Response.Content = new StringContent("Security Failed", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

ConfigItems class

```
/// <summary>
/// ConfigItems class
/// </summary>
public class ConfigItems
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether API Security Enable
    /// </summary>
    public static bool APISecurityEnable
    {
        get
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APISecurityEnable"]))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value APIToken
    /// </summary>
    public static string APIToken
    {
        get
        {
            return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIToken"];
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it in controller in like this.

```
[AuthorizeAPIAttribute]
public class MainController : ApiController
{
}
```

Now when you pass security key from angular service that will check in above filter.

```
angular.module('userApp').factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function () {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers['Security'] = "Key";
            return config;
        }
    };
});
angular.module('userApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'angular.filter']).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
}]);
```

As above you can set security key globally in you project.

Comment: Ok thank you, i will try as you have suggested, if it does not work, please help me. And thanks again :)

Comment: Okay try it.. i think it will definitely work because its working in my project.

Comment: @junaidameen if its working then mark as accept answer so other people can know this is working code.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the 'ConfigItems', if it is a class what properties do we need to add. And what about 'angular.filter' is there any plugin for this?

Comment: It just one class where i have created some property from where i can access app settings from web.config file. edited answer.

Comment: 'key' for 'APIToken' and true or false for 'APISecurityEnable'.. for now you have to set 'APISecurityEnable' as true.

Comment: if you do not mind, may i know what values we have to set for 'APISecurityEnable' and 'APIToken' in web.config?? As per my understanding you have set 'key' for 'APIToken', and for 'APISecurityEnable', do i need to set true or false?? hope am going right

Comment: Hey I got it man, this what i exactly wanted. Thank you so much :-)